# Packing function argument

Tags: python

I want to call a function sending several arguments inside a single variable.

In other words, I wanted to do `Test(some_var)` with the same result as `x1` in the example.

```
class Test:    
    def __init__(self, one, two=None):
        self.one = one

        if two is not None:
            self.two = two


tup = 'a', 'b'
lst = ['a', 'b']

x1 = Test('a', 'b')
x2 = Test(tup)
x3 = Test(lst)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `*` operator to unpack a tuple or list:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, one, two=None):
        self.one = one
        if two is not None:
            self.two = two


tup = 'a', 'b'
lst = ['a', 'b']

x1 = Test('a', 'b')
x2 = Test(*tup) # unpack with *
x3 = Test(*lst) # unpack with *
print(vars(x1) == vars(x2) == vars(x3)) # True
```

If you have keyword arguments and a `dict`, you can also unpack the dict with two `*`s:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, one=None, two=None):
        self.one = one
        if two is not None:
            self.two = two

kwargs = {'one': 'a', 'two': 'b'}

x1 = Test('a', 'b')
x2 = Test(**kwargs)
print(vars(x1) == vars(x2)) # True
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

The unpacking operator is very versatile and is not just for function arguments. For example:

```
>>> [*range(4), 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> {'x': 1, **{'y': 2}}
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to unpack the argument using operator `*`:

```python
Test(*tup)
```

By the way, operator `*` is used when you want to assign **arguments by position**. If you want to assign **arguments by name** you can use operator `**` in with a dictionary:

```
def foo(a, b):
    print(a, b)

kwargs = {'b': 20, 'a': 0}

foo(**kwargs) # 0 20
```

Comment: @bad_coder please, if this worked for you, mark it as accepted (green checkmark). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I think that actually my answer was given first (a few seconds) but you are right, @Tomothy32's answer is better than mine, at least more elaborate) so I agree with your choice. Thnx for upvoting anyway!